# Remove read topic from DDS

Tags: publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service

I have a problem with subscribing the data (using the java platform). When a subscriber subscribes to a topic, that subscribed data must be removed from the DDS.  But in my case whenever I subscribe to the data the same data is subscribed many times.  The data is not removed from the DDS.  I tried with QoS but I don't know how to use it.

Please suggest how I can remove the read data from the DDS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is not caused by your QoS settings, but by your method of accessing the `DataReader`. When you retrieve your data, you are probably calling something like the following `read()` in a loop:

```
FooReader.read(
    dataSeq, infoSeq, 10,
    ANY_SAMPLE_STATE.value,
    ANY_VIEW_STATE.value,
    ANY_INSTANCE_STATE.value);
```

The `read()` method invoked like this will return all currently available samples in your `FooReader`. After the `read()`, those samples still remain available in the `FooReader`, that is how the `read()` method behaves. Think of a read as a "peek". The next time that you invoke the `read()` method in this way, you will see all samples that you saw before, unless they have been overwritten by a new update from a `DataWriter`.

To resolve your issue, you could replace the `read()` with a `take()`, like this:

```
FooReader.take(
    dataSeq, infoSeq, 10,
    ANY_SAMPLE_STATE.value,
    ANY_VIEW_STATE.value,
    ANY_INSTANCE_STATE.value);
```

The `take()` method is different from the `read()` method in that it does a destructive read; it not only reads the data but also removes it from `FooReader`. That way, you will never receive the same sample twice. In fact, if you consistently use `take()` as opposed to `read()`, you will never be able to see any sample twice.

Another way to resolve your issue is to stick with `read()`, but adjust the requested `SAMPLE_STATE`, from `ANY` to `NOT_READ`, like this:

```
FooReader.read(
    dataSeq, infoSeq, 10,
    NOT_READ_SAMPLE_STATE.value,
    ANY_VIEW_STATE.value,
    ANY_INSTANCE_STATE.value);
```

That way, you will only read samples that you have not read previously. The difference with `take()` in this case is that the data does remain available in your `FooReader`, which might be useful if you want to re-read it at a later stage (in which case you need to use the `ANY` sample state as opposed to `NOT_READ` to obtain previously read samples).

Comment: Thank you Reinier. This is really userful and solve my issue.

Comment: You are welcome. Please make sure to accept any responses that answer your questions by clicking on the check-mark -- you currently have accepted zero answers for any of your six questions. See some instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Hi Rinier, Now, what my requirement is I have many subscribers but the publisher is single. My subscriber reads the data from the DDS and checks the message is for that particular subscriber. If the checking success then only it takes the data and remove from DDS. The message must maintain in DDS until the authenticated subscriber takes it's data. How can i achieve this using DDS (in java environment)??

Comment: Since this is a separate kind of issue that probably requires some of discussion, please pose this as a new question.